# Rstudio to Twitter handshake giving Error: Unauthorized via twitterR

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, rstudio

I am trying to authenticate Rstudio to Twittter using twitteR.

I only error after the handshake.

My code is:

```
#install(rcurl, ROAuth, twitteR)
#load(rcurl, ROAuth, twitteR)
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "key"
consumerSecret <- "secret key"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package =  "RCurl")))
twitCred$handshake()
```

I get the handshake and it send me to the auth page for Twitter. I authorize and get a pin.

I enter the pin in this code:

```
registerTwitterOAuth(pin number here)
```

Then I am returned with a "Error: Unauthorized".

I added a new Twitter application account and got a different set of customer keys, but still got the same.

Comment: Note that you're not authenticating "RStudio" to Twitter, just R. RStudio is just the IDE you are using to edit and run the code. (Similarly, you wouldn't say "connect iPython to...")

Comment: I mentioned RStudio as I see that sometimes it has its own issues when working with twitter. Not sure why.

Comment: update: I did this in the regular R consule and got one step further. Now I error when I do a searchtwitter:  

searchTwitter('patriots', geocode='42.375,-71.1061111,10mi')
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this step:

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "Mjn6tdsadsadkasdklad2SV1l"
consumerSecret <- "58Z7Eldsdfaslkf;asldsaoeorjkfksaVCQtvri"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

After you run this code you will see in R console message like this :

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=scmVODruosvz6Tdsdadadasdsa
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:
```

Just paste the link to your browser then authorize app, last one you will get the PIN code, just copy and paste the PIN code to your R console.

```
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

R console will show TRUE if you success.

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
userTimeline(user, n=20, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE)
```

If still any problem just try to show your package version and update to the last version

```
sessionInfo()
update.packages()
```

The last version for twitteR is 1.1.7 => http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Following the below steps made my code work after trying out the suggestions from every possible resource over the net!!!!  I am using windows 7, 64 bit and RStudio for the code below

Make sure you've got all appropriate packages installed - ROAuth, twitteR, RCurl; Usually the  dependencies indicated on the CRAN page will point you to the missing packages if any

Set SSL certs globally as shown in the code; I am not an expert as to why this is required but it > helped me get my code through Use download.file command to download the cacert.pem file  Make sure your twitter app has full  read write access and not just the read only access which is  the default

Final Code to link with Twitter

Get appropriate libraries

```
    library(twitteR)
    library(ROAuth)
    library(RCurl)
```

Set SSL certs globally

```
   options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

   download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
```

Make sure the url's are https and not http in case you have copied the code from somewhere

```
    reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
    accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"


    consumerKey <- "====="

    consumerSecret <- "====="


    twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                                 consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                                 requestURL=reqURL,
                                 accessURL=accessURL,
                                 authURL=authURL)

    #twitCred <- getTwitterOAuth(consumer_key= consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret)


    twitCred$handshake()
```

At this point you need to paste the URL into the browser which will open a twitter page with your  > application - you need to get the PIN from there and paste it in the R Console

```
 registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

TESTTHE CODE: Now you can test the code

```
testSearch = searchTwitter("#food", n = 10, cainfo="cacert.pem")
Moditweets <- searchTwitter("#Narendra Modi", n = 100)
```

Comment: Turn the comments into normal text and this will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, windows 8, note that authentication must be done in cmd, it cant happen via Rstudio IDE, you want to authenticate R as language

```
#Open admin shell: In the Start Search box, type cmd, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
#Goto C:/...R../bin/x64, run ./r.exe

install.packages("twitteR") #Takes some time for mirrors to pop-up
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")
requestURL <- ...
accessURL <- ...
authURL <- ...
consumerKey <- ...
consumerSecret <- ...
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=requestURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
save(list="twitCred", file="twitteR_credentials")
## Now to get some tweets, place the files cacert.perm and 

twitteR_credentials from bin folder to the the current working directory of Rstudio
library (twitteR)
load("twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
searchTwitter('#Obama', cainfo="cacert.pem", n=5, locale = 'en')
```